# How to measure the accuracy of performance.now

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out what the accuracy of `performance.now` is in Chrome. Using the following code:

```
const results = []
let then = 0
for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    const now = performance.now()
    if (Math.abs(now - then) > 1e-6) {
        results.push(now)
        then = now
    }
}
console.log(results.join("\n"))
```

I am getting the following results:

```
55058.699999935925
55058.79999976605
55058.89999959618
55058.99999989197
55059.09999972209
```

My understanding is that these values are in seconds, which means that each measurement is roughly 100ms apart. Is my testing methodology flawed or is performance.now actually limited to 100ms resolution in Chrome? I looked online and what I found stated the accuracy to be 100μs with 100μs jitter.

Answer (score 1):

These results are in milliseconds (55K **seconds** would mean you had your page opened for 15 Hours when this script did execute...)

As for the precision, this is now browser dependent and subject to change when better solutions against TimeBased attacks will be found, but yes, Chrome does limit the accuracy (0.1s) and add jitter (±0.1ms), Firefox does limit even further (1ms by default) and also adds jitter (though there you can set these options), Edge does like Chrome according to [this comment](https://github.com/w3c/hr-time/pull/57#issuecomment-369332355), and it seems Safari does a 1ms clamp only...